# Sum of values below a cell

Tags: sql, databricks

Table currently looks like this:

```
| Days Since Install | Installs |
| ------------------ | -------- |
|         1          | A        |
|         2          | B        |
|         3          | C        |
|         4          | D        |
```

I need the table to show me the sum of Values below a cell:

```
| Days Since Install | Installs |
| ------------------ | -------- |
|         1          | A+B+C+D  |
|         2          | B+C+D    |
|         3          | C+D      |
|         4          | D        |
```

Is it possible to generate a sql that can return the table above?

thanks for your help!

Comment: `sum(Days) over (order by Days rows between current row and unbounded following)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH RankedTable AS (
    SELECT 
        [Days Since Install],
        Installs,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Days Since Install]) AS RowNum
    FROM 
        temp
)
SELECT 
    rt.[Days Since Install],
    SUM(rt2.Installs) AS Installs
FROM 
    RankedTable rt
JOIN 
    RankedTable rt2 ON rt2.RowNum >= rt.RowNum
GROUP BY 
    rt.[Days Since Install]
ORDER BY 
    rt.[Days Since Install];
```

Hope it solves your query

Demo : https://dbfiddle.uk/m-PoyiBC

Comment: Might be useful to show this working in https://www.db-fiddle.com/.

Comment: Edited my response.
https://dbfiddle.uk/m-PoyiBC